# Refresh en Javascript similar al sleep()

Tags: javascript, async-await, refresh

Estoy intentando hacer un refresh en una web sin que se recargue la web completa cada segundo, sino únicamente los datos que obtengo del servidor:

```
<!-- <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1"> -->
<script>
window.onload=datos;
async function datos(){
    let url = 'http://localhost/consultas_php/json.php';
    let ps = await (await fetch(url,{mode:"no-cors"})).json();
    console.log(ps);
}
</script>
```

He intentado:

```
for(;;) setTimeout( datos(), 1000 );
```

Pero me bloquea el navegador:
[image: Navegador ralentizado]

¿Qué alternativas tengo para que, mientras espera, la ejecución no consuma recursos en el cliente?

Comment: Podrias mover el setTimeout dentro de la funcion asíncrona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como comentaba anteriormente, con la función `setInterval` podrás hacer que una función se ejecute de manera continúa a menos que se detenga con un `clearInterval`.

Ejemplo de reproducción continúa con `setInterval`

```
setInterval(datos, 1000); // cada segundo
```

Ejemplo con `clearInterval`

```
var timer = setInterval(datos, 1000);
// aquí en este ejemplo usaremos setTimeout para detener el setInterval después de 5 segundos
setTimeout(function () {
  clearInterval(timer);
  // se detiene el setInterval
}, 5000);
```

**Editado**

Por ultimo, la función `setTimeout` se ejecuta después del tiempo especificado. En este caso en el ejemplo que puse, le especifique a `setTimeout` que ejecute el clearInterval después de haber transcurrido 5 segundos

Comment: Espero haberme explicado bien xd

Comment: ¡Perfectamente! Y mucho más sencilla que la solución que había localizado. Aunque no es necesario que se detenga, sería para implementar un sistema de visualización, así que indefinidamente está perfecto. Sólo me queda una duda, pero la planteo en otra consulta diferente, que esta yo creo que ya está respondida... te dejo el enlace a continuación.

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente he conseguido localizar algo que me permite liberar recursos de la máquina y dejar la página disponible para otras interacciones (hay otros onclick):

```
const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

async function inicio(){
    for(;;){
        datos();
        await(delay(1000));
    }
}
```

La fuente ha sido: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226803/wait-5-seconds-before-executing-next-line

Si alguien conoce alguna opción más eficiente, será un placer intentarla.

Comment: Es mas fácil hacerlo con un `setInterval`. El `setInterval` a diferencia de `setTimeout`, este se reproducirá indefinidamente hasta que sea detenido mediante un `clearInterval`